# Why didn't Charles Xavier escape?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-2

In *X2: X-Men United*, when William Stryker was meeting Charles, before forcing him to use Cerebro, why didn't Professor-X use his powers to escape? He was able to read Stryker's mind as suggested in the movie.

[image: Xavier has the deivce on his head looking at Stryker who is staring back at him]

Comment: Can't speak for any of the other voters, but my DV is for lack of research. This is clearly explained in the scene. Why Xavier didn't use his powers at Magneto's prison, however, is a separate issue.

Comment: @phantom42 - He was being gassed.

Comment: @Richard Will respond in chat to keep the comments uncluttered.

Comment: Downvoted - that very scene discusses why he can't do anything to Stryker. If nothing else, there's a button on the remote called "rewind".

Comment: I felt that my answer was pretty comprehensive. Is there anything else you'd like to see before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 10):

Stryker explains that the blue LED light hat thing on Professor X's head is called a [neural inhibitor](https://xmenmovies.fandom.com/wiki/Neural_Inhibitor). It evidently prevents his telepathy from working:

> **Stryker :** *Please, Xavier, don't get up...* ***I call it the neural inhibitor*** [indicating the skullcap]
>
> *It keeps you outta here* [taps head]

Answer (score 1):

The Professor never actually read William Stryker's mind. He simply observed that Stryker held control over Deathstrike, and realized with horror that he had controlled Kurt Wagner/Nightcrawler:

> **Xavier**: You arranged the attack on the President.
> **Stryker**: *[mockingly]* And you didn't even have to read my mind.

The reason he could not read Stryker's mind, or escape for that matter, was the Neural Inhibitor, a personalized device for dealing with telepaths, most notably, Charles. As stated by Stryker, "It keeps you... out of here", as he taps the side of his head, grinning mischievously.